# How to make different worksheets in an Excel workbook viewable to some users and not others?

Tags: microsoft-excel, collaboration

I've been building out an Excel operating model for a company I work with and we're at a point where we want to share this model with their broader team. 
 We're aiming for a few things...

1) Some worksheets are relevant to some users, but not to others.  Moreover, some worksheets contain sensitive data that should only be viewable to certain users.  So we really need to be able to control view and edit settings at the worksheet and user level.

2) We'd like multiple users to be able to work on the workbook at the same time.

What's the best way to accomplish this?  Also, is OneDrive or SharePoint the optimal solution here, or are there other approaches that are just as good or better?  (In case it's relevant, I use Excel via Office 365.)

Comment: Are the worksheets just data in cells, or are their graphs/charts? To my knowledge, Excel itself doesn't really have the audience restrictions you're looking for, but Sharepoint does. It just depends on what you need to display.

Comment: @jrichall, as of right now, it's just data and formulas.

Comment: If it's just data and formulas, I would look into creating sharepoint lists that feed into your excel files. You can control permissions much easier on sharepoint than you can with excel. Look into building custom lists with item level permissions, then linking those lists to excel which can feed your formulas.